# Bash Script Command Line Argument Batch Stdin (heredocs)

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I have a program that asks for stdin a few seconds after it startups. I would like to send it the stdin from the command line instead of manually typing it out. I've done the following:

```
./program.sh << EOF
./program.sh <<< EOF
./program.sh << 'input'
./program.sh <<< 'input'
```

but none work. Why aren't heredocs working in this case?

Comment: Does `echo 'input' | ./program.sh` work?

Comment: The first method should have worked.  How did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

The program probably thinks itself more interactive than it really is and ignores input that doesn't arrive at the right time. `telnet` is notorious for this. The options are:

1. The good way: Use `expect` to interactively wait for a prompt and input a response.
2. The bad way: Try to time responses and hope it works,

e.g.

```
{ sleep 5; echo "foo"; sleep 5; } | ./program.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

`<<` denotes a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents)

```
./program.sh <<END
hello
world
END
```

`<<<` denotes a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

```
./program.sh <<< "hello world"
```

If the input is generated somehow, use a pipe or redirect from a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
helloWorldGenerator.sh | ./program.sh
./program.sh < <(helloWorldGenerator.sh)
```